# Trying to implement an Alarm Clock in Verilog, my clock works but my alarm doesn't

Tags: verilog, clock, alarm, intel-fpga

I implemented the clock module, which worked. But, then I tried to add the alarm functionality to it, and the code just broke. Now I have no idea what's wrong with it!

I would really appreciate some help on this, as I'm unable to implement this, and it's a homework assignment that is due tomorrow.

```
module inputmux(alarm_key_out, alarm_sw_out, clock_key_out, clock_sw_out, select, key_in, sw_in);
    //Used to direct the control input to the alarm/clock
    output reg alarm_key_out, alarm_sw_out, clock_key_out, clock_sw_out;
    input select, key_in, sw_in;
    
    always@(select)
    case (select)
        0: begin
                clock_key_out = key_in;
                clock_sw_out = sw_in;
            end
        1: begin
                alarm_key_out = key_in;
                alarm_sw_out = sw_in;
            end
    endcase
endmodule

module outputmux(hours_out, minutes_out, select, alarm_min_in, alarm_hours_in, clock_min_in, clock_hours_in);
    parameter n = 8;
    
    output reg [n-1 : 0] hours_out, minutes_out;
    input [n-1: 0] alarm_min_in, alarm_hours_in, clock_min_in, clock_hours_in;
    input select;
    
    always @(select)
        case (select)
            0: begin
                hours_out = clock_hours_in;
                minutes_out = clock_min_in;
            end
            1: begin
                hours_out = alarm_hours_in;
                minutes_out = alarm_min_in;
            end
        endcase
endmodule

//Right now our counter only counts to 30 (or 12). If we change it to 60 then 1 minute == 2 minutes in real time.
//Check if the hour rolls over from at 30, I suspect that the clock hits 30, then has to hit 30 again. In which case it's a BCD error.
//Note: a roll over will *not* occur if the clock is in manual mode. 
module nBitCounter(count, reset_sig, CLK, manCLK, toggle);
    parameter n = 8; // output size defualt 8 bit, must be able to store bitwise k  value 
    parameter k = 30; // ceiling

    output reg [n-1:0] count;
    output reg reset_sig; //Meant for a high output when count resets
    input CLK, manCLK, toggle;
    
    wire clockline;
    assign clockline = toggle ? manCLK : CLK;
        
    // Increment count on clock + also has seed value
    always @(posedge clockline) //or posedge seed <- this breaks things
    begin
        if (count == k-1) begin
            count = 0;
            reset_sig = ~reset_sig;
        end
        else begin 
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end
endmodule


module demuxer(a, s_in, x, y);
input a;
input s_in;
output reg x, y;

always @(a, s_in)
begin
    case(s_in)
        1: x = a;
        0: y = a;
        default: x = a;
    endcase
end
endmodule

module sevenSegmentDisplay(ssOut, nIn);
  output reg [0:6] ssOut;
  input [3:0] nIn;

    always @(nIn)
        case (nIn)
            4'b0000: ssOut = 7'b0000001;
            4'b0001: ssOut = 7'b1001111;
            4'b0010: ssOut = 7'b0010010;
            4'b0011: ssOut = 7'b0000110;
            4'b0100: ssOut = 7'b1001100;
            4'b0101: ssOut = 7'b0100100;
            4'b0110: ssOut = 7'b0100000;
            4'b0111: ssOut = 7'b0001111;
            4'b1000: ssOut = 7'b0000000;
            4'b1001: ssOut = 7'b0001100;
    endcase

endmodule

module binary_to_BCD(A,ONES,TENS,HUNDREDS);
    input [7:0] A;
    output [3:0] ONES, TENS;
    output [1:0] HUNDREDS;
    wire [3:0] c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7;
    wire [3:0] d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7;
    
    assign d1 = {1'b0,A[7:5]};
    assign d2 = {c1[2:0],A[4]};
    assign d3 = {c2[2:0],A[3]};
    assign d4 = {c3[2:0],A[2]};
    assign d5 = {c4[2:0],A[1]};
    assign d6 = {1'b0,c1[3],c2[3],c3[3]};
    assign d7 = {c6[2:0],c4[3]};
    add3 m1(d1,c1);
    add3 m2(d2,c2);
    add3 m3(d3,c3);
    add3 m4(d4,c4);
    add3 m5(d5,c5);
    add3 m6(d6,c6);
    add3 m7(d7,c7);
    assign ONES = {c5[2:0],A[0]};
    assign TENS = {c7[2:0],c5[3]};
    assign HUNDREDS = {c6[3],c7[3]};
endmodule

module add3(in,out);
input [3:0] in;
output [3:0] out;
reg [3:0] out;

always @ (in)
    case (in)
    4'b0000: out <= 4'b0000;
    4'b0001: out <= 4'b0001;
    4'b0010: out <= 4'b0010;
    4'b0011: out <= 4'b0011;
    4'b0100: out <= 4'b0100;
    4'b0101: out <= 4'b1000;
    4'b0110: out <= 4'b1001;
    4'b0111: out <= 4'b1010;
    4'b1000: out <= 4'b1011;
    4'b1001: out <= 4'b1100;
    default: out <= 4'b0000;
    endcase
endmodule

module alarmstatecontroller(buzzerout, alarmtoggle, alarmstop, alarmstart, clk);
    // This is the FSM. The buzzerout (currently represented by LEDG) does not actually 
    // turn off. It may have to do with the switch in which case we can remove it. I don't think
    // namespace is an issue but look into it. It might be worth while to assign LEDs to the states to see if
    // they actually change. 
    output reg buzzerout;
    input alarmtoggle, alarmstop, alarmstart, clk;
    
    wire trigger, dead;
    assign trigger = alarmtoggle ? alarmstart : dead;
    
    parameter n = 3;
    parameter IDLE = 3'b001, RING = 3'b010;
    
    reg [n - 1:0] STATE;
    
    always @(trigger or alarmstop)
    begin
        case(STATE)
            IDLE:
                begin
                    buzzerout = 'b0;
                    if (trigger)
                        STATE = RING;
                end
            RING:
                begin
                    if (alarmstop)
                        STATE = IDLE;
                    else begin
                        buzzerout = 1'b1;
                    end
                end
            default: STATE = IDLE;
        endcase
    end
endmodule

module alarmregister(alarmtrigger, clockhour, clockminute, alarmhour, alarmminute);
    output reg alarmtrigger;
    input [7:0]clockhour, clockminute, alarmminute, alarmhour;
    
    always @(clockminute, clockhour, alarmminute, alarmhour)
    begin
        if (clockminute == alarmminute && clockhour == alarmhour) begin
            alarmtrigger = 1'b1;
        end else begin
            alarmtrigger = 'b0;
        end
    end
endmodule

module clock(HEX3, HEX2, HEX1, HEX0, LEDR, LEDG, SW, KEY, CLOCK_50);
    output [0:6]HEX3, HEX2, HEX1, HEX0;
    output [1:0]LEDR, LEDG;
    input [3:0] SW, KEY;
    input CLOCK_50;
    supply0 groundline;
    
    wire mainclock, minuteclock, hourclock, inputtoclocksetsw, inputtoclocksetkey, clocksetminute, clocksethour;
    wire alarmsetminute, alarmsethour, inputtoalarmsetkey, inputtoalarmsetsw, alarmtofsm;
    wire [3:0] bcdminutesones, bcdminutestens, bcdhoursones,bcdhourstens;
    wire [7:0]displayminutes, displayhours, clockminutesoutput, clockhoursoutput, alarmminutesout, alarmhoursout;
    
    //Controls whats displayed on the HEX displays
    inputmux ChangeInputController(inputtoalarmsetkey, inputtoalarmsetsw, inputtoclocksetkey, inputtoclocksetsw, SW[2], ~KEY[0], SW[0]);
    outputmux ChangeOutputController(displayhours, displayminutes, SW[2], alarmminutesout, alarmhoursout, clockminutesoutput, clockhoursoutput);
    demuxer ClockDeMux(inputtoclocksetkey, inputtoclocksetsw, clocksetminute, clocksethour);
    demuxer AlarmDeMux(inputtoalarmsetkey, inputtoalarmsetsw, alarmsetminute, alarmsethour);
    
    //Display Control
    binary_to_BCD Minutes(displayminutes,bcdminutesones,bcdminutestens,HUNDREDS);
    binary_to_BCD Hours(displayhours,bcdhoursones,bcdhourstens,HUNDREDS);
    
    sevenSegmentDisplay HexDisplayMinutesZero(HEX0, bcdminutesones);
    sevenSegmentDisplay HexDisplayMinutesOne(HEX1, bcdminutestens);
    sevenSegmentDisplay HexDisplayHoursZero(HEX2, bcdhoursones);
    sevenSegmentDisplay HexDisplayHoursOne(HEX3, bcdhourstens);
    
    //Create seconds tick
    nBitCounter ClockDelay(count, mainclock, CLOCK_50, seed, toggle);
    defparam ClockDelay.n = 25;
    defparam ClockDelay.k = 25000000;
    
    assign LEDR[0] = mainclock;
    
    
    //Count Seconds
    nBitCounter SecondsTick(count, minuteclock, mainclock, seed, SW[1]);
    //Count Minutes
    nBitCounter MinutesTick(clockminutesoutput, hourclock, minuteclock, clocksetminute, SW[1]);
    //Count Hours
    nBitCounter HoursTick(clockhoursoutput, reset_sig, hourclock, clocksethour, SW[1]);
    defparam HoursTick.k = 12;
    
    //Alarm Minutes
    nBitCounter AlarmMinuteCounter(alarmminutesout, reset_sig, CLK, alarmsetminute, SW[1]);
    //Alarm Hours
    nBitCounter AlarmHourCounter(alarmhoursout, reset_sig, CLK, alarmsethour, SW[1]);
    defparam AlarmHourCounter.k = 12;
    
    //Alarm Triggering
    alarmregister AlarmRegisterComp(alarmtofsm, clockhoursoutput, clockminutesoutput, alarmhoursout, alarmminutesout);
    assign LEDR[1] = alarmtofsm;
    //When the FSM is enabled the LED (means alarm is triggered) does not light up.
    //alarmstatecontroller AlarmSoundControl(LEDG[0], SW[3], ~KEY[2], alarmtrigger, mainclock);
endmodule
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I think my finite state machine is wrong, because when I run the comparator (and comment out the FSM), it triggers the LED light which i assign to the alarm signal. But when I create a wire that connects it to the FSM, my whole code breaks and gets buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incomplete sensitivity lists.  Change *most* of your `always` lines to:

```
always @*
```

**Except** for your sequential logic (for example, `posedge`).